# java rabbitMQ: setup securityContext readOnlyRootFilesystem fail to create cookeis file

Tags: java, kubernetes, rabbitmq

rabbitMQ implementation with k8s.
I want to add securityContext with readOnlyRootFilesystem: true

It fail to deployed because it tries to write cookeis files to the file system.

1. How do I setup rabbitmq to use different path for the cookies?
2. how do I setup rabbitmq to use the volume that I defined in the mount instead of the HOME dir for all data?

## **The deployment file:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "rabbitmq.namingConvention" . }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  labels: {{ include "rabbitmq.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels: {{ include "rabbitmq.selectorLabels" . | nindent 6 }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: {{ include "rabbitmq.selectorLabels" . | nindent 8 }}
      annotations:
        {{- if and (.Values.global.metrics.enabled) (not .Values.global.metrics.usePrometheusServiceMonitor) }}
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
        {{- end }}
    spec:
      {{- with .Values.global.imagePullSecrets }}
      imagePullSecrets: {{- toYaml . | nindent 6 }}
      {{- end }}            
      **securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 100
        runAsGroup: 100**
      containers:      
      #########################################
      ########## RABBITMQ CONTAINER #########
      #########################################
      - name: {{ .Values.global.namePrefix }}-smp-rabbitmq
        image: "{{ .Values.global.imageRegistry }}/{{ .Values.global.imageRepository }}/{{ .Values.rabbitmq.containers.rabbitmq.image.name }}:{{ .Values.rabbitmq.containers.rabbitmq.image.tag }}"
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.global.imagePullPolicy | default .Values.rabbitmq.containers.rabbitmq.image.pullPolicy | quote }} 
        resources:
          requests: {{- include "rabbitmq.resources" . | nindent 12 }}
          limits: {{- include "rabbitmq.resources" . | nindent 12 }}                    
        ports:
        - name: rabbitmqnonsec
          protocol: TCP
          containerPort: {{ .Values.rabbitmq.service.nonsecure.targetPort }}
        - name: rabbitmqsec
          protocol: TCP
          containerPort: {{ .Values.rabbitmq.service.secure.targetPort }}
        **securityContext:
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false**
        env:
          - name: HOME
            value: "/opt/rabbitmq"
        volumeMounts:
          - name: {{ .Values.rabbitmq.persistence.rabbitmq_data.name }}
            mountPath: /var/lib/rabbitmq
      volumes:
      - name: {{ .Values.rabbitmq.persistence.rabbitmq_data.name }}
        {{- if .Values.global.storage.enabled }}
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: {{ include "rabbitmq.namingConvention" . }}-{{ .Values.rabbitmq.persistence.rabbitmq_data.name }}
        {{- else }}
        emptyDir: {}
        {{- end }}
```

## **the error:**

```
2022-07-28 06:17:23.028733+00:00 [erro] <0.145.0>     exception error: "Failed to create cookie file '/opt/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie': erofs"
2022-07-28 06:17:23.028733+00:00 [erro] <0.145.0>       in function  auth:init_no_setcookie/0 (auth.erl, line 293)
2022-07-28 06:17:23.028733+00:00 [erro] <0.145.0>       in call from auth:init/1 (auth.erl, line 144)
2022-07-28 06:17:23.028733+00:00 [erro] <0.145.0>       in call from gen_server:init_it/2 (gen_server.erl, line 423)
2022-07-28 06:17:23.028733+00:00 [erro] <0.145.0>       in call from gen_server:init_it/6 (gen_server.erl, line 390)
2022-07-28 06:17:23.028733+00:00 [erro] <0.145.0>     ancestors: [net_sup,kernel_sup,<0.47.0>]
```

Answer (score 0):

The cases when your **HOMEDRIVE** and **HOMEPATH** get overridden by group policy of AD user and then it is needed to set your **HOMEDRIVE** variable each time you want to start RabbitMQ service. In this case do the following 5 steps :

1. rabbitmq-service remove service
2. edit ***rabbitmq-service.bat*** file:

   "!ERLANG_HOME!\bin\erl.exe" ^
   -pa "!RABBITMQ_EBIN_ROOT!" ^
   -boot !CLEAN_BOOT_FILE! ^
   -noinput -hidden ^
   -s rabbit_prelaunch ^
   -setcookie "C:\Users\userName" ^ <<< Place of your cookie
   !RABBITMQ_NAME_TYPE! rabbitmqprelaunch!RANDOM!!TIME:~9!@localhost ^
   -conf_advanced "!RABBITMQ_ADVANCED_CONFIG_FILE!" ^
   ..."
3. save the script
4. `set HOMEDRIVE=C:\Users\userName`
5. `rabbitmq-service install`